# Json giving null value

Tags: json, laravel

I have some problem with saving a JSON array.

I have a dropdown for classes through which I can get the student data using ajax. I can get the student data but now I wanna store this data after clicking the save button. Now when I do `return dd($request->all())`; this in my store action then it giving me the JSON array where all the required data is available but when I try to get the individual value then it is giving me the null value. Below is my code

### My ajax

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $.ajaxSetup({
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                }
            });
        });

        $('select[name="class_id"]').on('change', function() {
            var classID = $(this).val();
            if(classID) {

                $.ajax({

                    url: '/myform/ajax/'+classID,
                    type: "GET",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success:function(data) {

                        var attendance = `<div class="form-group">
                    <select class="form-control" id="attendance" name="attendance[]">
                        <option>Present</option>
                        <option>Absent</option>
                        <option>Leave</option>
                    </select>
                    </div>`;

                        var markup = '';
                        markup += '<tr> <th>#</th> <th>Student ID</th> <th>Student Name</th> <th>Attendance</th> <tr>';

                        $.each(data, function(key, value) {

                             markup += '<tr> <td><input type="hidden" value="'+value.id+'" name="id[]">' + value.id + '</td> <td><input type="hidden" value="'+value.student_id+'" name="student_id[]">' + value.student_id + '</td> <td><input type="hidden" value="'+value.first_name+'" name="first_name[]"><input type="hidden" value="'+value.last_name+'" name="last_name[]">' + value.first_name+ ' '  + value.last_name  + '</td> <td> ' + attendance +  '</td> <tr>';

                        });
                        $('table[id="studentsData"]').html(markup);


                        $('body').on('click', '#save-btn', function(e){

                            e.preventDefault();

                            var data = $('#studentsData').find('select, input').serialize();
                            var data = {data: data, class_id: $('[name="class_id"]').val()};

                            $.post('/students/attendance', {data: data},  function(response){
                                console.log(response);
                            });
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });

</script>
```

### Student attendance table structure

```
 public function up()
 {
        Schema::create('students_attendances', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('class_id')->index()->unsigned()->nullable();
            $table->string('student_id');
            $table->string('first_name');
            $table->string('last_name');
            $table->string('attendance');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
 }
```

### Controller

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    return dd($request->all());
}
```

Comment: Add your controller class in the description so I can help you.

Comment: There is nothing in my controller action but i can show you. Check the updated answer

Comment: You tried to use $request->get('attendance') or $request->attendance or request()->get('attendance') to see if the value is returned?

Comment: I used something like this 'return $request->get('student_id');' But now i am getting nothing before it was giving me null word at the backend but now it just give me the blank page

Comment: I really dont get the point because when i do return dd($request->all()); in the store action then it give me the proper array with the required values but not able it to store

Comment: it give me array like this at the back end after using that line of code                             array:1 [
  "data" => array:2 [
    "data" => "id%5B%5D=1&student_id%5B%5D=hk123&first_name%5B%5D=hasnain&last_name%5B%5D=khan&attendance%5B%5D=Present"
    "class_id" => "1"
  ]
]

Comment: I think I understood the problem. Your request is incorrect, the data is coming in the index "data". If you use $request->get('data')['data'] you will see that the data is coming as a string, not an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing you need to do is putting the click event out of the change event (You shouldn't nest events).

The second change is removing the second ready function, you just need the first one.

```
$('body').on('click', '#save-btn', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var data = $('#studentsData').find('select, input').serialize();
  data = {
    data: data,
    class_id: $('[name="class_id"]').val()
  };

  $.post('/students/attendance', data, function(response) {
    console.log(response);
  });
});
```

**NOTE:** You don't have to declare the `data` two times, and you don't have to put an object inside another one like you do in `{data: data}`, the `data` is an object already so just send it.

About the serialize you could simply use `parse_str()` like :

```
parse_str($all['data'], $information)
```

Now you could loop through the `$information` as you want.

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $info = \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input::all();

    $class_id = $info['class_id'];
    parse_str($info['data'], $input);

    foreach($input['student_id'] as $i => $student_id) {
        StudentsAttendance::create([
            'class_id' => $class_id ,
            'student_id' => $student_id,
            'first_name' => $input['first_name'][$i],
            'last_name' => $input['last_name'][$i],
            'attendance' => $input['attendance'][$i]
        ]);

        return redirect()->back();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your javascript script:

```
var formdata = $('#studentsData').find('select, input').serializeArray();
var data = {};
$(formdata ).each(function(index, obj){
    data[obj.name] = obj.value;
});

data[class_id] = $('[name="class_id"]').val();

$.post('/students/attendance', data, function(response){
    console.log(response);
});
```

Comment: Now can you pls explain me that how i can store the data. Which method will be the best ?

Comment: Use the Eloquent model to persist your data. Example: YourModel::create($request->only(['class_id','student_id','first_name','last_name','attendance']));